# SSH Tunnel on different networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, putty

I'm trying to set up a SSH connection between my personal pc from home and my laptop which will be on a different network. I've read a bit about SSH connections and I saw that I had to open port 22 on my pc. I entered the router settings (I have an edimax BR-6428nS) and on the port forwarding I entered the details to open the port. Next, on my pc I installed Bitvise SSH Server and I started the server. On my laptop, I installed Putty in order to connect to my pc. Now comes the problem, from my local network, when I'm at home the connection works and I am able to connect to my pc but I'm on the same network. I tried to connect from a different network and I just get connection timed out on putty...Can you guys help? Thanks!

#### Router Settings:

[image: Router Settings]

#### Server Settings:

[image: Server Settings]

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting to the public ip address of your router and not `192.168.2.101` when at the remote location, right?

Try these:

1. First test connecting when on same network, but do not connect to local ip address of the PC - use public ip address of the router instead.
2. If above works and you still cannot connect to the PC from different network then try pinging your router - to verify it is possible connect to it.
3. Finally, your service provider (either at home or at the remote location) might be blocking port `22` TCP traffic. Switch configuration of Bitvise SSH and on your router to port `80` or `443` and test if it works now.

Also consider to set up static ip address for your home PC - don't use DHCP lease (automatic ip address) because your setup could easily break if the PC decides to get different than `192.168.2.101`.